# The "Close Votes" queue presents me with a locked question

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I can do nothing about [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/647933) except clicking <kbd>Not Sure</kbd> because the [question is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414323/vb-net-price-calculation). So I guess it's kind of pointless to show it to me in the first place.

> [image: Review locked question]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locked posts shouldn't appear in the Close Votes queue any more now. Thanks for the report.